# python string find and look up on string until found space from json

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-transform

Below is my data.

```
'{"Data": {"a":5647953897,"b":"323299901059958183671030","c":1605858513465}}{"Data": {"a":5647953897,"b":"323299901059958183671030","c":1605858513465}}'
```

My output should be as below

```
[{"a":5647953897,"b":"323299901059958183671030","c":1605858513465},{"a":5647953897,"b":"323299901059958183671030","c":1605858513465}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your case.

```
from json import JSONDecoder, JSONDecodeError
import re

NOT_WHITESPACE = re.compile(r'[^\s]')

data = '''{"Data": {"a":5647953897,"b":"323299901059958183671030","c":1605858513465}}{"Data": {"a":5647953897,"b":"323299901059958183671030","c":1605858513465}}'''

def decode_stacked(document, pos=0, decoder=JSONDecoder()):
    while True:
        match = NOT_WHITESPACE.search(document, pos)
        if not match:
            return
        pos = match.start()

        try:
            obj, pos = decoder.raw_decode(document, pos)
        except JSONDecodeError:
            raise
        yield obj
        
for obj in decode_stacked(data):
    print(obj)
```

Comment: You are the gem . Thanks a ton. my work has progressed further bro. Which location are you from ?. IF its ok to reveal you can tell. But thank you again

Comment: You very well understood my intent

Comment: @NaveenSrikanth Happy to help you. Also please accept my answer also. My email is yashkan27@gmail.com